# How do i understand this macro definition

Tags: c

I came across this macro definition

```
#define CAN1      ((CAN_TypeDef *) CAN1_BASE)
```

and i want to understand the concept behind. `CAN_TypeDef` is a data  structure and its definition is as follows

```
typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t              MCR;                 /*!< CAN master control register,         Address offset: 0x00          */
  __IO uint32_t              MSR;                 /*!< CAN master status register,          Address offset: 0x04          */
  __IO uint32_t              TSR;                 /*!< CAN transmit status register,        Address offset: 0x08          */
  __IO uint32_t              RF0R;                /*!< CAN receive FIFO 0 register,         Address offset: 0x0C          */
  __IO uint32_t              RF1R;                /*!< CAN receive FIFO 1 register,         Address offset: 0x10          */
  __IO uint32_t              IER;                 /*!< CAN interrupt enable register,       Address offset: 0x14          */
  __IO uint32_t              ESR;                 /*!< CAN error status register,           Address offset: 0x18          */
  __IO uint32_t              BTR;                 /*!< CAN bit timing register,             Address offset: 0x1C          */
  uint32_t                   RESERVED0[88];       /*!< Reserved, 0x020 - 0x17F                                            */
  CAN_TxMailBox_TypeDef      sTxMailBox[3];       /*!< CAN Tx MailBox,                      Address offset: 0x180 - 0x1AC */
  CAN_FIFOMailBox_TypeDef    sFIFOMailBox[2];     /*!< CAN FIFO MailBox,                    Address offset: 0x1B0 - 0x1CC */
  uint32_t                   RESERVED1[12];       /*!< Reserved, 0x1D0 - 0x1FF                                            */
  __IO uint32_t              FMR;                 /*!< CAN filter master register,          Address offset: 0x200         */
  __IO uint32_t              FM1R;                /*!< CAN filter mode register,            Address offset: 0x204         */
  uint32_t                   RESERVED2;           /*!< Reserved, 0x208                                                    */
  __IO uint32_t              FS1R;                /*!< CAN filter scale register,           Address offset: 0x20C         */
  uint32_t                   RESERVED3;           /*!< Reserved, 0x210                                                    */
  __IO uint32_t              FFA1R;               /*!< CAN filter FIFO assignment register, Address offset: 0x214         */
  uint32_t                   RESERVED4;           /*!< Reserved, 0x218                                                    */
  __IO uint32_t              FA1R;                /*!< CAN filter activation register,      Address offset: 0x21C         */
  uint32_t                   RESERVED5[8];        /*!< Reserved, 0x220-0x23F                                              */ 
  CAN_FilterRegister_TypeDef sFilterRegister[28]; /*!< CAN Filter Register,                 Address offset: 0x240-0x31C   */
} CAN_TypeDef;
```

---

the `CAN1_BASE` is defined as below.

```
/*!< Peripheral memory map */
#define APB1PERIPH_BASE        0x40000000UL
#define CAN1_BASE             (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x6400UL)
```

Question : Does the macro definition `CAN1` assign a starting address to the data structure `CAN_TypeDef` or does it mean anything else. I know that the macro gives this hexadecimal value of  (`0x40000000UL+ 0x6400UL`) to `CAN1`. However, the inclusion of this data structure like a pointer definition is something that i am trying to conceptualize.

Comment: Could you please show all code fragments formatted as code. Also, you show no definition of  `CAN_TypeDef`, which seems key to the question.

Comment: @JasperKent : I have added the definition

Answer (score 2):

it is very simple.

lets make it a buit more simple.

```
#define PERIPHADDR  0x12345678

typedef struct
{
    volatile uint32_t REG1;
    volatile uint32_t REG2;
    volatile uint32_t REG3;
    volatile uint32_t REG4;
    volatile uint32_t REG5;
}PERIPH_t;

#define PERIPH  ((PERIPH_t *)(PERIPHADDR))


void foo()
{
    PERIPH -> REG1 = 0x45678;
}
```

and it expands to

```
void foo()
{
    ((PERIPH_t *)(0x12345678)) -> REG3 = 0x45678;
}
```

> Does the macro definition CAN1 assign a starting address to the data
>   structure CAN_TypeDef or does it mean anything else

No it does not assign any address. It just calculates where it has to store the value. Without any intermediate pointers.

You may ask question why not define "a normal" pointer. The answer is simple. It will waste the memory and generate less efficient code:

example:

```
#define PERIPH  ((PERIPH_t *)(PERIPHADDR))

PERIPH_t *PERIPH1 = (PERIPH_t *)PERIPHADDR;


void foo()
{
    PERIPH -> REG3 = 0x45678;
}

void bar()
{
    PERIPH1 -> REG3 = 0x45678;
}
```

and the resulting code:

```
foo:
        ldr     r3, .L3
        ldr     r2, .L3+4
        str     r2, [r3, #128]
        bx      lr
.L3:
        .word   305419776
        .word   284280
bar:
        ldr     r3, .L6
        ldr     r2, .L6+4
        ldr     r3, [r3]
        str     r2, [r3, #8]
        bx      lr
```

Comment: Thank you so much @P__J__ , for the detailed explanation. It was very helpful